# How to Model a delay in Verilog without # ? That can be synthesized

Tags: verilog, delay, clock

I am looking to create an AND gate which gets the result after a delay of lets say 10ns an my clock is 500 ps. How will i delay the assignment without using # delays ?

I have tried to make a counter which increments but how to model it so that it only starts when my input changes. Also the input won't change till the first output is evaluated and assigned. Initial Counter is 0 and lets say delay is 3'b111 so i want the counter to go from 1 to 3'b111 and then assign it to y. Inputs are a and b to the and gate.

```
always@(posedge clk)begin
  if (!reset) begin y <=0; counter <=0; end
  else begin
   counter <= counter +1'b1;
   if(counter==delay)begin
     y <= a & b;
     counter <=0;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if your clock cycle is 500 ps then you will need to count to a higher value to reach 10ns. I rewrote your code and also added a testbench for you to try. It's kind of sloppy, I usually write vhdl and not verilog. Hope this helps.

```
//Module

module count_and (
    input clk,
    input reset,
    input a,
    input b,
    output reg y,
    output reg [4:0] counter
);

reg ready;

always@(posedge clk)begin
  if (!reset) begin 
    y <=0; 
    counter <=0; 
    ready <= 0;
  end
  else if (ready == 1'b1) begin
   counter <= counter +1'b1;
   if (counter==5'b10011) begin
     y <= a & b;
     counter <=0;
     ready <= 0; //turn it off after passing to y
   end
  end
 end

always @(a,b) begin
  ready <= 1'b1;
 end

endmodule

    //TestBench
`timescale 1ps/1ps
module tb_count ();

reg a,b;
reg clk;
reg reset;
wire [4:0] counter;
wire y;

initial begin
clk = 1'b1;
reset = 1'b0;
a = 1'b0;
b = 1'b0;
end

always begin
reset <= #50 1'b1;
clk = #250 ~clk;


a <= #1000 1'b1;
b <= #1000 1'b1;
end


count_and count_and_inst (
    .clk(clk),
    .reset(reset),
    .a(a),
    .b(b),
    .y(y),
    .counter(counter)
);

endmodule
```

Comment: Hey Laburtz, Thanks for the detailed Help. But apart from the glaring mistake of higher count value. My concern is that my counter will increase based on clock but it should increase whenever my inputs A and B change and from that point it should start the counter till it reaches delay value. That is not happening in our codes.

Comment: In our case, counter is starting from the reset signal. What if my input starts after a while from the reset point. At that point my counter has already started and is nearing the delay value and it will give the output prematurely

Comment: I modified my original post to do what you asked for. I set it up to reset the counter and stop it until a or b change again. If you want to keep the counter going. Just deleted the "ready <= 0;" under the if statement. Oh and the delay is 9.75ns so you might have to tweak things a little to get the 10ns you want.

Comment: Thanks Laburtz, that Worked for me! i did not think of two always block to do the required task.